# how to show() geoplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am a novice in Geoplot, so it looks I need a help.
I use PyCharm for my test project.

The task is to build and show some charts.
With pyplot it works without any problem: I build a chart and then show() it.

```
plt.scatter(x, y, z, c = z)
plt.show()
```

Now I try to do the same with geoplot.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geoplot as gplt

usa_cities = gpd.read_file(gplt.datasets.get_path('usa_cities'))
print(usa_cities.head())

continental_usa_cities = usa_cities.query('STATE not in ["HI", "AK", "PR"]')
gplt.pointplot(continental_usa_cities, figsize=(8, 4))
```

The question is: how to show the plot in pycharm?

PS. Yes, geoplot plots work in jupiter. But I need it in pycharm.

Possible at all?

Comment: It just return a matplotlib axes, so it should not be different for gplot.

Comment: @steven Thanks a lot! Could you make remark as an answer and I will rate it up with a pleasure?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to assign the returned Axes into a Figure object and then show the Figure.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import geoplot as gplt

usa_cities = gpd.read_file(gplt.datasets.get_path('usa_cities'))
continental_usa_cities = usa_cities.query('STATE not in ["HI", "AK", "PR"]')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
gplt.pointplot(continental_usa_cities, ax=ax)
fig.show()
```